# jQuery: how to address a sub item with a special class

Tags: jquery, class, object-address

I want to iterate over the **line** elements. Each **line** element has **item** elements as child elements. So first I iterate over **line** and then I want to address a certain **item** element e.g. the third. This is the code I have:

```
$(".pricetable .righttable .line:not(.blank)").each(function(j) {
    var currentLine = $(".pricetable .righttable .line:not(.blank)").eq(j);
    currentLine.(".item").each(function(k) {
        $(".pricetable .righttable .line .item").eq(i).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

The problem is that I don't know how to address the child element with the **item** class.

```
currentLine.(".item").each(function(k)
```

This does not work.

XML filter is applied to non-XML value ({0:#2=({}), length:1, prevObject:{length:3, prevObject:{0:#1=({}), context:#1#, length:1}, context:#1#, selector:".pricetable .righttable .line:not(.blank)", 0:#2#, 1:({}), 2:({})}, context:#1#, selector:".pricetable .righttable .line:not(.blank).slice(0,1)"})
file:///C:/Users/xxx/lib/pricetable.js
Line 112

**Edit:**
Wow, I didn't thought I get such a good and fast response! I think I go with this solution:

```
$(".pricetable .righttable .line:not(.blank)").each(function(j) {
    $(this).children(".item").eq(i).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".pricetable .righttable .line:not(.blank)").each(function(j) {
    var currentLine = $(".pricetable .righttable .line:not(.blank)").eq(j);
    currentLine.find(".item").each(function(k) {
        $(".pricetable .righttable .line .item").eq(i).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/find/

If they're direct children of currentLine, you should just be able to do `children('.item')` in place of `find('.item')`. This is called Traversing the DOM. Visit this page (http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) and read through the descriptions of some of the functions there. They'll be very useful to keep in mind if you traverse a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.pricetable .righttable .line:not(.blank)').find('.item').each(function() {
  // this point to child element - item
  // use $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do something with the nth `item` of each `line`, it's much easier than it looks:

```
var index = 3; // the third "item" element 
$(".pricetable .righttable .line:not(.blank) .item:nth-child(" + index + ")")
  .addClass("active");
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/zRXdz/)**.

Is there something else you want to do that the above is not sufficient for?

Answer (score 2):

Slight improvement before I answer your question:

```
var currentLine = $(".pricetable .righttable .line:not(.blank)").eq(j);
```

is easily replaceable with:

```
var currentLine = $(this);
```

---

Second, if you wish to find the 3rd `.item` element inside of `$(this)`, use `.find()`

```
.find(".item:nth-child(3)");
```

No need to iterate over the lines. If you must iterate over the lines, then just compare `k` to `2` (As JavaScript counts from 0) and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".pricetable .righttable .line:not(.blank)").each(function() {
  $(this).find('.item:nth-child(2)').addClass('active');
});
```